# jQuery picture slider issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I want to make a simple picture slideshow using html and jquery. I have tried the code below. it only shows the firt image and it does not slide to the next image automatically.

I just want to make these three simple images to slide horizontally forever.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#slideShow{
position:absolute;
height:490px;
width:490px;
background-color:#fff;
margin:10px 0 0 10px;
z-index:100;

-moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #111;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #111;
box-shadow:0 0 10px #111;
}

#slideShow ul{
position:absolute;
top:15px;
right:15px;
bottom:15px;
left:15px;
list-style:none;
overflow:hidden;
} 

#slideShow li{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="slideShow">
<ul>
<li><img src="7.png" /></li>
<li><img src="77.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="777.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
jQuery("#slideShow").slider({
orientation: "horizontal",
range:"min",
min: 1,
max: 4,
value: 1,
slide: function( event, ui ) {

}
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
    <div class="yourimg_container">
         <img  src="http://localhost/app/img/off.png" id="Image1"/>
      </div>

      /* make an array containing your images path (you can fetch images from database   using asp.net/php query)*/

       var ss=  ["http://localhost/app/img/off.png",
               "http://localhost/app/img/on.png",
               "http://localhost/app/img/slider.png"];


      window.setInterval(function(){
          slideshow();
        }, 3000);

      function slideshow(){
        var im=$("#Image1").attr("src");

        for(i=0;i<ss.length;i++){

            if(ss[i]==im){
                if(i==ss.length-1) $('#Image1').attr("src",ss[0]);  
                else $('#Image1').attr("src",ss[i+1]);  
            }
        } 

      }
```